# Allow to filter deleted posts by source of deletion in the 10 k tools (or it least indicate the source)

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, deleted-posts

From time to time I check the deleted posts in the 10 k tools (http://[site].stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete) as to whether any posts have been deleted by other 10 k users that shouldn’t (of which there are too many on a given site in my opinion). However, this task is made unnecessarily tedious by all the deletions by the roomba script (i.e., the community user) which equally appear on the list and are usually deleted for a good reason at an appropriate time. Relatedly, posts deleted by a diamond moderator are also usually deleted for a good reason or just answers converted to comments.

It would therefore be great to have some way to filter the post by who deleted them, as this distinguishes between different kinds of deleted posts:

- If it’s deleted by the community user, it’s an old, closed questions with no upvoted answers and similar. (And thus usually not worth a look.)
- If it’s deleted by an admin, it’s either utter junk or an answer converted to a comment. (Again, usually not interesting.)
- If a post is deleted by 10 k users or via the low-quality queue, this can very well be due to users who misunderstood the purpose of the *delete* button or the ([still horribly explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220794/255554)) low-quality queue. (Very worth a look.)

As an alternative to such a filter, there could at least be an indicator next to the post as to which of the above applies.

Comment: On one of the sites I'm active on we sometimes have the opposite situation: community deletions are generally sound, but sometimes the Roomba is a little over-zealous (with obscure, long-tail questions we want to keep).  Having a filter or some indication of source would help.

Comment: We're talking about the `Recently Deleted` section on http://[site.com]/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days (and other days), right? If so, they don't show posts deleted by the OP (see the tooltip for it)... But I might be looking in the wrong place...? +1 anyway.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: Yes we are talking about that. I never noticed that it excludes self-deleted posts (in fact, I now know that there is a tool for diamond moderators for this) – thanks for the information. I removed the respective bullet points.

Answer (score 2):

The first two of your three categories can probably be folded together by indicating which diamond deleted it; if you see Community there, you know what the deal is. Alternatively, show username on hover of the diamond symbol next to each deleted post.

The last should probably be broken up a bit more: the distinction between "deleted because of a Recommend Deletion review outcome on a ≤0-score post" and "deleted because enough 10k or 20k users voted to delete independently of any flags" is a useful one, I think. In the former case, linking to the review would be very handy; in the latter, showing usernames (possibly only on hover) would be OK, but not absolutely essential in the tools.

---

(I got access to 2k tools recently, and ELL volume is not enough that this is absolutely essential, but it would certainly be handy, and on e.g. SO I can only imagine how unpleasant the current state of affairs is.)